# How do I take ownership of a registry key via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, registry, acl

I'm attempting to take ownership of a registry key via PowerShell, and it's failing silently. I'm using the following code:

```
# get the username of the current user
$uname = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

# create an identity reference for the owner
$user = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($uname)

# create a "drive" for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
new-psdrive -name HKCR_zf -psprovider Registry -root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

# change the current location
set-location HCKR_zf:\CLSID

# set ACLs
(get-acl '{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}').setowner($user)
```

Everything runs fine up to the last line, but the .setowner() call fails silently (the owner is not changed).

How do I take ownership of a registry key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling `SetOwner` doesn't commit the change.  You need to pass the acl object back to `Set-Acl` to commit the change.

Check out this thread, there is a good description and full sample code.  Seems there are some other hoops to jump through, as well: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/e718a560-2908-4b91-ad42-d392e7f8f1ad

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes script don't have necessary ownership, privileges or permissions for changing registry values. It needs for admin privileges. Next script takes permissions recursively for all subkeys.

Call examples:

```
# group BULTIN\Users takes full control of key and all subkeys
Take-Permissions "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\test"

# group Everyone takes full control of key and all subkeys
Take-Permissions "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\test" "S-1-1-0"

# group Everyone takes full control of key WITHOUT subkeys
Take-Permissions "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\test" "S-1-1-0" $false
```

You just should define next func:

```
function Take-Permissions {
    # Developed for PowerShell v4.0
    # Required Admin privileges
    # Links:
    #   http://shrekpoint.blogspot.ru/2012/08/taking-ownership-of-dcom-registry.html
    #   http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/01/16/take-ownership-of-a-registry-key-in-powershell/
    #   https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/controlling-registry-acl-permissions-with-powershell/

    param($rootKey, $key, [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$sid = 'S-1-5-32-545', $recurse = $true)

    switch -regex ($rootKey) {
        'HKCU|HKEY_CURRENT_USER'    { $rootKey = 'CurrentUser' }
        'HKLM|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'   { $rootKey = 'LocalMachine' }
        'HKCR|HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT'    { $rootKey = 'ClassesRoot' }
        'HKCC|HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG'  { $rootKey = 'CurrentConfig' }
        'HKU|HKEY_USERS'            { $rootKey = 'Users' }
    }

    ### Step 1 - escalate current process's privilege
    # get SeTakeOwnership, SeBackup and SeRestore privileges before executes next lines, script needs Admin privilege
    $import = '[DllImport("ntdll.dll")] public static extern int RtlAdjustPrivilege(ulong a, bool b, bool c, ref bool d);'
    $ntdll = Add-Type -Member $import -Name NtDll -PassThru
    $privileges = @{ SeTakeOwnership = 9; SeBackup =  17; SeRestore = 18 }
    foreach ($i in $privileges.Values) {
        $null = $ntdll::RtlAdjustPrivilege($i, 1, 0, [ref]0)
    }

    function Take-KeyPermissions {
        param($rootKey, $key, $sid, $recurse, $recurseLevel = 0)

        ### Step 2 - get ownerships of key - it works only for current key
        $regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::$rootKey.OpenSubKey($key, 'ReadWriteSubTree', 'TakeOwnership')
        $acl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity
        $acl.SetOwner($sid)
        $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)

        ### Step 3 - enable inheritance of permissions (not ownership) for current key from parent
        $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $false)
        $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)

        ### Step 4 - only for top-level key, change permissions for current key and propagate it for subkeys
        # to enable propagations for subkeys, it needs to execute Steps 2-3 for each subkey (Step 5)
        if ($recurseLevel -eq 0) {
            $regKey = $regKey.OpenSubKey('', 'ReadWriteSubTree', 'ChangePermissions')
            $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($sid, 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
            $acl.ResetAccessRule($rule)
            $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)
        }

        ### Step 5 - recursively repeat steps 2-5 for subkeys
        if ($recurse) {
            foreach($subKey in $regKey.OpenSubKey('').GetSubKeyNames()) {
                Take-KeyPermissions $rootKey ($key+'\'+$subKey) $sid $recurse ($recurseLevel+1)
            }
        }
    }

    Take-KeyPermissions $rootKey $key $sid $recurse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using IDs such as `{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}` you need to use `""`

For example: `(HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\"{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}",Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::takeownership)`

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a clarifcation form an other post, but it is really important!

For the script posted last, be sure to add a security that checks for the $key. Otherwise you would overwrite all RegKeys in the particular rootkey.

Going back to a restore point does not work as computer-accounts do not have access anymore to the hole rootkey.

Something like:
if ($key.length -eq 0) {
  write-host "key parameter must be set"
  return
}

Answer (score 0):

A variation on another answer.  This only sets ownership.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
 Give ownership of a file or folder to the specified user.

.DESCRIPTION
 Give the current process the SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" and "SeRestorePrivilege" rights which allows it
 to reset ownership of an object.  The script will then set the owner to be the specified user.

.PARAMETER Path (Required)
 The path to the object on which you wish to change ownership.  It can be a file or a folder.

.PARAMETER User (Required)
 The user whom you want to be the owner of the specified object.  The user should be in the format
 <domain>\<username>.  Other user formats will not work.  For system accounts, such as System, the user
 should be specified as "NT AUTHORITY\System".  If the domain is missing, the local machine will be assumed.

.PARAMETER Recurse (switch)
 Causes the function to parse through the Path recursively.

.INPUTS
 None. You cannot pipe objects to Take-Ownership

.OUTPUTS
 None

.NOTES
 Name:    Take-Ownership.ps1
 Author:  Jason Eberhardt
 Date:    2017-07-20
#>
function Take-Ownership {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$false)]
  Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [switch]$Recurse)

  Begin {
    $AdjustTokenPrivileges=@"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public class TokenManipulator {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
      internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
      internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
      internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    internal struct TokPriv1Luid {
      public int Count;
      public long Luid;
      public int Attr;
    }

    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
    internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
    internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;

    public static bool AddPrivilege(string privilege) {
      bool retVal;
      TokPriv1Luid tp;
      IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
      IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
      retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
      tp.Count = 1;
      tp.Luid = 0;
      tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
      retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
      retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
      return retVal;
    }

    public static bool RemovePrivilege(string privilege) {
      bool retVal;
      TokPriv1Luid tp;
      IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
      IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
      retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
      tp.Count = 1;
      tp.Luid = 0;
      tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
      retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
      retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
      return retVal;
    }
  }
"@
  }

  Process {
    $Item=Get-Item $Path
    Write-Verbose "Giving current process token ownership rights"
    Add-Type $AdjustTokenPrivileges -PassThru > $null
    [void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege") 
    [void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeRestorePrivilege") 

    # Change ownership
    $Account=$User.Split("\")
    if ($Account.Count -eq 1) { $Account+=$Account[0]; $Account[0]=$env:COMPUTERNAME }
    $Owner=New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Account[0],$Account[1])
    Write-Verbose "Change ownership to '$($Account[0])\$($Account[1])'"

    $Provider=$Item.PSProvider.Name
    if ($Item.PSIsContainer) {
      switch ($Provider) {
        "FileSystem" { $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity]::new() }
        "Registry"   { $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity]::new()
                       # Get-Item doesn't open the registry in a way that we can write to it.
                       switch ($Item.Name.Split("\")[0]) {
                         "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"   { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot; break }
                         "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"  { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine; break }
                         "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"   { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser; break }
                         "HKEY_USERS"          { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::Users; break }
                         "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentConfig; break }
                       }
                       $Key=$Item.Name.Replace(($Item.Name.Split("\")[0]+"\"),"")
                       $Item=$rootKey.OpenSubKey($Key,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::TakeOwnership) }
        default { throw "Unknown provider:  $($Item.PSProvider.Name)" }
      }
      $ACL.SetOwner($Owner)
      Write-Verbose "Setting owner on $Path"
      $Item.SetAccessControl($ACL)
      if ($Provider -eq "Registry") { $Item.Close() }

      if ($Recurse.IsPresent) {
        # You can't set ownership on Registry Values
        if ($Provider -eq "Registry") { $Items=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } }
        else { $Items=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force }
        $Items=@($Items)
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $Items.Count; $i++) {
          switch ($Provider) {
            "FileSystem" { $Item=Get-Item $Items[$i].FullName
                           if ($Item.PSIsContainer) { $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity]::new() }
                           else { $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity]::new() } }
            "Registry"   { $Item=Get-Item $Items[$i].PSPath
                           $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity]::new()
                           # Get-Item doesn't open the registry in a way that we can write to it.
                           switch ($Item.Name.Split("\")[0]) {
                             "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"   { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot; break }
                             "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"  { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine; break }
                             "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"   { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser; break }
                             "HKEY_USERS"          { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::Users; break }
                             "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" { $rootKey=[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentConfig; break }
                           }
                           $Key=$Item.Name.Replace(($Item.Name.Split("\")[0]+"\"),"")
                           $Item=$rootKey.OpenSubKey($Key,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::TakeOwnership) }
            default { throw "Unknown provider:  $($Item.PSProvider.Name)" }
          }
          $ACL.SetOwner($Owner)
          Write-Verbose "Setting owner on $($Item.Name)"
          $Item.SetAccessControl($ACL)
          if ($Provider -eq "Registry") { $Item.Close() }
        }
      } # Recursion
    }
    else {
      if ($Recurse.IsPresent) { Write-Warning "Object specified is neither a folder nor a registry key.  Recursion is not possible." }
      switch ($Provider) {
        "FileSystem" { $ACL=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity]::new() }
        "Registry"   { throw "You cannot set ownership on a registry value"  }
        default { throw "Unknown provider:  $($Item.PSProvider.Name)" }
      }
      $ACL.SetOwner($Owner)
      Write-Verbose "Setting owner on $Path"
      $Item.SetAccessControl($ACL)
    }
  }
}

Take-Ownership -Path "Registry::HKCR\CLSID\{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}" -User "Administrator" -Recurse -Verbose
```

Answer (score -2):

@Slogmeister and the author of the original, I must say thank you I could not get this sorted. And you helped me do so, just one question, could you elaborate on the logic behind this, what permission structure is above admin, such that an admin trying to take ownership would fail(as it did before your script)? Also, what subsystems are involved and where could one go to learn about them. Ie, what is the script interacting with and how and why :) I know...But it's important to know, as this little exersise proved. I was basically trying to reinstall SSDT and because some key was not allowing alterations it failed, as well as a host of other packages, everything SQL related basically.
Thanks a mill, whether you have time to elaborate or not...

```
Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Components
```

That was the offending key.

Comment: Hi you should put this as a comment, not an answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry What? Did you read the comment or just glance at the last line, which is just a footnote.