# Taking ownership over registry key in Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I am trying to take ownership of this key via installer (to automate work):

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}
```

or

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}
```

By default, the owner is `TrustedInstaller`. I cannot do this via `HKCU` because the change is supposed to work for all users (changing RunAs to _RunAs).

I use the command (or `Root: HKCR` ofc):

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\AppID{{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}"; ValueType: string; Permissions: admins-full
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\AppID\{{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}"; ValueName: "RunAS"; Flags: deletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\AppID\{{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "_RunAS"; ValueData: "Interactive User"
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\AppID\{{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}"; ValueType: dword ; ValueName: "AppIDFlags"; ValueData: "1"
```

Unfortunately nothing happens, on the other computer where I manually set the owner to "users" after running this command only the permissions are added but the owner unfortunately remains the same. Of course I run everything with administrator rights and I have read the whole
[`Registry` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection).

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup cannot change owner of the key.

But you can ask Inno Setup to re-create the key using the [`deletekey` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=deletekey). What should change the owner to the account that runs the installer as a side effect. But it will obviously delete all subkeys and values too.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\AppID{{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}"; \
  Flags: deletekey
```

---

If you need to change the owner, while preserving the contents, you will have to run an external tool for that. Like a PowerShell code:
[How do I take ownership of a registry key via PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12044432/850848)